# サイトの多言語化後、検索に反映されない

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

HTMLページの多言語化を行い、

英語版http~.com
日本語版http~~~.com/ja/

という構成にしました。

しかし、日本語で検索した時も英語版のタイトルのほうでヒットしてしまいます。

alternate,hreflangタグも両方に"en"、"ja"の２つをつけています。
しかし検索に表示されません。

懸念される事項としては、ブラウザ言語に応じて自動でリダイレクトするJSスクリプトを実装していることです。
（例：英語版サイト(.com)に日本語設定の人が行くと日本語版(.com/ja/)に自動遷移する。逆も然り）

また、fetch as google からインデックス登録をリクエストする際に、クロールが完了したという表示は出ています。

どのような対策を取れば、英語検索には英語版、日本語検索には日本語版を表示できるでしょうか。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/121647

Answer (score 3):

Googleの「コンテンツに関するガイドライン」で、言語による自動リダイレクトは否定されています。検索エンジンは認識言語がjaではないので日本語版にアクセスできなくなっていると思われます。

> ユーザーの認識言語に基づいて自動的にリダイレクトしないようにしてください。このようなリダイレクトを行うと、ユーザー（と検索エンジン）がサイトのすべての言語バージョンを見られなくなる場合があります。

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=ja&ref_topic=2370587

Comment: ありがとうございます。リダイレクトはしてはいけなかったのですね。

Comment: しかし、リダイレクトを外しても日本語版が検索にかかりません。これはまた別の原因があるのでしょうか。。。

Comment: Google Search Console で、「インデックス ステータス」で確認にしながら、インデックスされていないようだったら「クロール」の「Fetch as Google」でどうように見えるか確認後「インデックス登録をリクエスト」することを地道にしてみてください。

Comment: 個々のページがインデックスされているかどうかは、Googleの検索で「〇〇 site:example.com」のように自分のサイトの検索オプションを付けて検索してみるとよくわかります。